# Using wolfram to check biconditional involving predicates and quantifiers

Tags: wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I have a habit of trying out correctness about some logical statements with worlfram alpha by generating truth table for them. For example, I can try if this:

```
((¬x→y)∧(¬x→¬y))→x
```

is correct or not by geerating truth table for [`((¬x→y)∧(¬x→¬y))`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((not+x+implies+y)+and+(not+x+implies+not+y))) which turns out to be the same as `x` column in the same truth table. Hence the above is correct. However is there any way I can check same for biconditionals involving nested existential and universal quantifiers and predicates? For example can I somehow verify rules of this kind?:

```
(∀x)(∀y)ϕ(x,y)⇔(∀y)(∀x)ϕ(x,y)
```

**Update**

I am able to do following check `∀x,y(x∨y)` as follows:

[`Resolve[ForAll[{x,y}, x or y]]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resolve%5BForAll%5B%7Bx,y%7D,+x+or+y%5D%5D)

which correctly returns `False` as `(x∨y)` does not hold for all `x` and `y`.

So now I thought I can do something similar to obtain `True` for following (which is a general fact): `¬(∀x)ϕ(x)⇔(∃x)¬ϕ(x)`. I tried this:

[`Resolve[ForAll[x,(not ForAll[x, x]) xnor (exists[x,not x])]]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resolve%5BForAll%5Bx,(not+ForAll%5Bx,+x%5D)+xnor+(exists%5Bx,not+x%5D)%5D%5D)

But it did not work. Note that `⇔` is nothing but `xnor`. So how do I do this especially something like following also correctly returns `True`:

[`Resolve[not ForAll[x, x]]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resolve%5Bnot+ForAll%5Bx,+x%5D%5D)

which stands for `¬∀x(x)`.